# How to train SVM correctly on a 1D dataset

Tags: machine-learning, svm, matlab, threshold

I am trying to use svmtrain (Statistic Toolbox) to train a linear (2 class) SVM on a 1D feature vectors. The features are not fully separable and the classes intersect.

The naive approach would be to search for the optimal threshold for a simple classification, but one can expect to get similar (or even the same) results using a linear SVM. I am using all the default parameters and the SVM gives a different threshold and performs much worse than searching for a threshold (0.73 accuracy with threshold search vs. 0.66 accuracy with SVM).

The motivation for the process is as follows: While 1D vectors can be separated into 2 classes using a simple threshold, when the dimension is > 1, the threshold approach is not feasible and requires an SVM (or similar methods) to find a separation. To make sure I configure and use the SVM correctly I first expect to get very similar results using threshold search and SVM on a 1D vectors.

Would be happy to know what am I doing wrong to get this kind of difference in performance.

Comment: just to be clear, you are doing a binary classification problem with a single (real valued?) feature, is that correct? also what type of data is this?

Comment: Yes, each feature is a double.

Comment: "each feature" -> there is only one, correct (1D)? also have you given it a value for `C` which enables soft margins?

Comment: Yes, 1D. I know I can simply search for the best threshold, but I want to use and SVM since I plan to increase the dimension of the feature vector.

C is 1 by default, no? (I am using Matlab's implementation 
[svmtrain](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html "Matlab's implementation"))